# when i am running my project, SIGABRT occur

Tags: iphone, xcode

This was the error:

```
  CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 256128 bytes
    CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 262208 bytes
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CAException'
    Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
    warning: Unable to read symbols for /Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
    kill
    gdb stack trace at 'putpkt: write failed':

    The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).
```

what was the reason?

Answer (score 0):

For the error try to open the debugger when you hit this error and see which line of code is causing it. That might help. Set environment variables to get more detailed error log.